# least squares minimum

Tags: summation, least-squares

it's the age old least-squares problem:

Find the value of b for which the following sum has the minimum value (assuming that x and y are one-dimensional vectors of the same length):

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - bx_i)^2 = min $$

This must have been asked before but I can't find it, would appreciate a redirect from somebody thanks

Comment: It's not an exact value I'm after obv

Comment: Usually $i$ starts at $\color{blue}1$, since you have $n$ observations.

Comment: oopsies, my apologies, it's a hard habit to break

Comment: No problem. You can make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Differentiate with respect to $b$ and equate to $0$.

Comment: maybe I'm going around in a circle but that gives me a value of 1 for b? that wouldn't make any sense...

Comment: @Biaaach, No, that gives you the equation $\sum x_i(y_i-bx_i)=0$. Simplify that.

Comment: am I wrong in assuming that this sum can be split into 
$$\sum_{}y^2 - 2b\sum_{}x + b^2 \sum_{}x^2$$

Edit: and if I differentiate that I end up with $$b = \frac{\sum_{}x}{\sum_{}x^2}$$

Comment: @Biaaach, you're missing a $y$ term in the middle. It should be $\sum xy$ instead of $\sum x$.

Comment: Also note that since this is a finite sum, you can differentiate term by term as well.

Comment: oh wow that's it now it all fits into the bigger picture-...  thanks for the correction and I'm sorry to have had to ask for verification

Answer (score 1):

If you know linear algebra, the LHS can be written as
$$
(y-bx)^T(y-bx)
$$
with $y=(y_0,y_1,\cdots y_n)^T$, $x=(x_0,x_1,\cdots x_n)^T$.

The minimization solution is given by
$$
b=(x^Tx)^{-1}x^Ty
$$

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation) for the general case.

Comment: At this article $i$ starts at $i=1$. I would do it the same way, since we have n observations.

Comment: @callculus: I think the index bound is not essential. One can adjust it under different contexts.

Comment: @mrsamy thanks for the article, the wikipedia page is wordy as always so gimme a minute to digest this lmao

Comment: thanks for your help @mrsamy , I had to vote for the other guy cuz his was a direct answer